# How can I remove the Cmd entry from a Docker image configuration?

Tags: docker

After modifying a Docker image "from within" by running

```
docker run -it --user root <image_name> bash
```

…and `commit`ing the changes, the image's config now contains the `bash` command in `Container.Cmd` and `ContainerConfig.Cmd`.

I have seen that `docker commit` at least used to have a `-run` option which could let me modify the configuration, but I haven't found documentation for it.

How can I remove `Cmd` from the configuration to make entrypoint active again (and what should I have done to avoid the problem)?

Comment: One option is to use a `Dockerfile` to generate your new image, rather than `docker run`, making changes, and `docker commit`.  This gives you a lot more control over the process and also leaves you with a reproducible set of steps.

Comment: That's what I usually do. In this case, however, I was trying to avoid having to save and transfer a 400 MB tar.gz docker image to another server using a slow internet connection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Workaround) You could run your new image with `docker run --entrypoint` to set a new entrypoint, then commit that new container as a new image. It should keep the entrypoint you started it with.

Alternatively you could manually edit the JSON metadata for the image, but I wouldn't recommend that as a production hack -- it is always better to go through the APIs for that.

Comment: Works like a charm. `Cmd` became `null` in the new image's config.